# Do all fermions having the same spin mean they all have the same intrinsic angular momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, fermions

All fermions are spin 1/2, but they have different "masses" does spin 1/2 mean they all have the same intrinsic angular momentum?

Comment: The different mass would lead me to believe the have different angular momentum s

Comment: I see your point about the different mass. But mass is a very salient feature of the theory, whereas spin, or any magnitude with dimensions of action, is a part of the axiomatic basis of the quantum formalism, and is much more constrained.

Comment: @Joe What do you think the magnitude of the intrinsic angular momentum of a particle of mass $m$ and spin $s$ is?

Comment: Spin has the same units as $\hbar$, $m^2 kg / s$, so it's already in angular momentum units and you can't get any useful physical quantity by multiplying it by a mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "spin" and "intrinsic angular momentum" are two names for the same quantity, of course having the same spin is equivalent to having the same intrinsic angular momentum. However, it is not the case that all fermions are spin-$\frac12$. A fermion is defined to be a particle which follows Fermi-Dirac statistics, which by the [spin-statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem) is any particle with half-integer spin. For example, [Delta baryons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon) and [iron-55 nuclei](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/nspin.html) are both spin-$\frac32$ fermions.

Answer (score 1):

All known fundamental fermions have spin 1/2.
As "intrinsic angular momentum" is just another name for shorthand "spin", the answer is yes.
You can, in principle, think of objects of spin 3/2, so-called Rarita-Schwinger fermions, or even higher. But there are arguments that they cannot be really fundamental, which somebody can complete here or maybe myself as soon as I find the time. I'm thinking of soft-boson theorems in QFT, combined with arguments of Poincaré invariance, if I remember correctly.